# RSASSA-PSS подпись с хэш функциейSHA256

Tags: c#, криптография, rsa, криптопро

Пытаюсь реализовать данный алгоритм 2 способами.

*Первый способ.* Есть X509 сертификат и его закрытый ключ в контейнере.
Пытаюсь создать подпись таким способом:

```
using (RSA privateKey = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey())
        {
           sign = privateKey.SignHash(hash, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,RSASignaturePadding.Pss);
        }
```

Как я понял, мне не удается получить закрытый ключ, т.к. его не даёт КриптоПро  в свойство PrivateKey у переменной cert имеет
`CryptoPro.Sharpei.Gost3410CryptoServiceProvider`. SDK КриптоПро у меня нет.

*Второй способ.* Пытаюсь реализовать алгоритм используя OpenPGP ключи. Нашёл стороннюю библиотеку Chilkat

```
Chilkat.Cert cert = new Chilkat.Cert();
success = cert.LoadFromFile(@"*ПУТЬ*.asc");
```

Но она не понимает что я ей подсовываю и ничего не открывает.

Какой именно ключ мне использовать разницы не имеет, но на данный момент есть X509 сертификат .cer и его ключ в контейнере, а так же пара OpenPGP ключей в файлах .asc

Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать, какие примеры посмотреть?

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение, оно как обычно оказалось элементарным.

Во время создания ключа нужно указывать криптопровайдер не CryptoPro, а Microsoft'овские. Любой из списка подходит. И в таком случае  код

```
using (RSA privateKey = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey())
        {
           sign = privateKey.SignHash(hash, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,RSASignaturePadding.Pss);
        }
```

начинает работать и генерировать подпись. Адекватная она или нет, я пытаюсь как-нибудь проверить, но при беглой проверке метод `privateKey.VerifyData` выдаёт на мою подпись `true`. Почему только с использованием закрытого ключа он выдаёт истину, мне пока не понятно, ведь должен быть использовать публичный.